# C# Filter DataGridView with multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

[image]

That's what it looks like. Student Lookup and Course Lookup search two different databases. I'm trying to display search results from the text boxes on the left. Here's what the database looks like.

[image]

This code is ran when a user clicks Submit. I retrieved it from another post but to no avail:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dgvAdvisor.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "First_Name like '%" + lblFirstName.Text + "%' AND 
        Username like '%" + lblUsername.Text + "%'";
        dgvAdvisor.DataSource = bs;
```

Lines 3 and 4 are one line, Stack Overflow seems to chop it up.

Any advice?

Comment: what exactly problem you are facing with this code ?

Comment: and also, you are trying to make first name looks like `lblFirstName` 's text , `lblFirstName` is `TextBox` or `Label` ?

Comment: @Amit the issue is I can't get the results to filter the searches from the text boxes but now I realize I don't even have the datagridview filled with the table.

Comment: and what about my second comment, `lblFirstName` is it label or textbox. you said you haven't data grid view filled with table, is it because of this problem in your data source only?

Comment: A lazy way to go about it is to filter it through sql query instead of using C# codes. Just insert query on either button or in an event.

Comment: @Amit My apologies. It's actually a textbox. It should be txtFirstName, not lblFirstName. The second half of your comment I'm not understanding...

Comment: In that case, lets try a basic thing first. I'm posting an answer try it out, and let me know if it works.

Comment: @P.Pat your suggestion works well, when OP doesn't have any problem in firing database query again and again. i would not prefer this way if my database is on some remote computer.

Comment: @P.Pat I thought about doing that as well. I'm bad at SQL so excuse me here but... what would that query even look like? If it helps, that table I posted is under Main_Information. I understand the "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE..." then I'm lost...

Comment: @tryingtotryhard you could go about it like this. `query = "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE First_Name like '%" + txtFirstName.Text + "%';";` in c# code under submit button assuming you already populated the `datagridview`. Just one line for the sample. But as Amit stated its not advisable albeit a lazy way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

From code you provided, it looks like you are filtering your data source with Label's text, and you want it to be filtered with TextBox's text.

Assuming your associated `TextBox` controls are `txtFirstName` and `txtUserName` ,
try modifying your code as follow.

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = GetDataTable(); //This method should return whole data table.
    bs.Filter = "First_Name like '%" + txtFirstName.Text + "%' AND 
    Username like '%" + txtUserName.Text + "%'";
    dgvAdvisor.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: I feel like this is definitely the fix but I realize now that I don't even have my DataGridView linked to my table. I feel like I'm using BindingSource incorrectly. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @tryingtotryhard have Bind `BindingSource` 's `DataSouce` to `DataTable` first ? in your code, I'm not seeing that part. it should look like `bs.DataSource = GetDataTable()` assuming GetDataTable method returns the data table which you have shown in question. Eidted my answer accordingly

Comment: @tryingtotryhard [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) may help you more.